# find the solution to the PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the problem, where α>0

$$                   
U_t=2Uxx, 0≤x≤2, t≤0
$$
$$
Ux(0,t)=-α , Ux(2,t)=0
$$
$$
U(x,0)=f(x)= -αx(1-(1/4)x)
$$

*By trying a function of the form u(x,t)=Ax² + Bx + Ct to deduce that a solution to this system is*
$$
U(x,t)=αx((1/4)x-1) + αt
$$

Answer (score 2):

To check that something is a solution, just plug it into the equations and see that they are true.  To discover a solution of the form $A x^2 + B x + C t$, plug that into the equations and see what the coefficients need to be to make the equations true.